# Can't export mesh to .fbx

Tags: export, .fbx

I'm new to Blender and I'm making a track for Assetto Corsa. It's an ambitious project but it's very important for me.
I can't export my track to a .fbx file. This error appears:
[image: error message]

I leave my [blend file](https://mega.nz/#!RhchjQpJ!6c9XFtYq4ipf5y_EhXjWbn3c1gSyPDcn9MwZz4zU7mY) for any checking you need. I uploaded it in mega because it exceeds the 30MB limit.

Comment: That should probably be reported in the [Blender bugtracker](http://developer.blender.org/), I don't think there much anyone here can do

Comment: What do you mean with "I don't think there is much anyone can do"?. I mean, will I have to remake the project from 0 or what? I'll post it on the bugtracker anyway while I wait for your anwer. Thank you.

Comment: For starters, please explain **exactly** what you did when you tried to export your file (and by "exactly" I mean a screenshot of the export panel on the left side of the file selector). Which objects did you select to export? Have you applied the modifiers? Have you joined the objects? Also: Please be more careful when posting links. Yours doesn't work and sometimes it understandably annoys experienced users if people don't put much effort into their questions.

Comment: No you don't have to redo everything, by "I don't think there is much anyone can do **here**". I meant that a well behaving script should never through a Python error at the user; if it does it is most likely a bug on unintentional behavior, and should be reported to the tracker. There are little to no developers here and probably few people able to fix it even if they wanted to.

Comment: Oh, just found the problem. There was a nurbs path which wasn't cyclic and was tiny, also without material.  When I deleted it it exported successfully. There were also modifiers not applyed and scales and rotations not applied. 
Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 1):

There was a nurbs path which wasn't cyclic and was tiny, also without material. When I deleted it everything was exported successfully.
There were also modifiers not applyed and scales and rotations not applied.