# Cannot export to FBX file, does anyone know how to fix this?

Tags: export

So basically I've been stuck on this for about 2 hours now, when I try to export the file I get this error message. I have seen a similar problem but didn't really get how he fixed it, any help is appreciated! The post I'm referring to is this one: [Can't export mesh to .fbx](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66234/cant-export-mesh-to-fbx).

[image: This is the error message I get when I try to export the file to FBX]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem may be an invalid UVW map. [Here](https://developer.blender.org/T79775) is the developer task associated with this error. You can try two things:

Run the following code in Blender before exporting until the bug is fixed (Credit  Michael Campbell):

---

```
import bpy

for ob in bpy.data.objects:
    if not ob.type =='MESH':
        print(ob.name,'is not a mesh, skipping\n')
        continue
    print(ob.name,'\n')
    m = ob.data
    if m.validate(verbose=True):
        print("something was fixed with the mesh")
    else:
        print("mesh was fine")
        
    print(" and the cached custom data has been cleared to avoid export issues")
```

If this doesn't work, try clearing and recreating the UV map. Make sure everything is unwrapped properly.

Another thing to check is to make sure all of your objects have correct location and scale values. Some people have reported export problems where certain objects somehow got set to `NaN` (Not a number) and weird scaling values.

As a last resort, I would try deleting everything from your scene one by one and try exporting to FBX after each and every deletion. This may help you narrow things down and isolate the culprit of the crash.

Comment: I honestly didn't think it would work, thank you so much!

Comment: No problem, glad to help! If you don't mind, please mark my answer as accepted.

Comment: Oh whoops sorry for not responding, its marked as accepted now.